# Not able to send / receive messages in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-640-xl

WhatsApp was working absolutely fine just an hour ago, suddenly it stopped receiving any messages nor I am able to send any. Internet connection is absolutely fine. I tried to reboot the phone and also reinstall whatsapp many times, but no use. Even using mobile data, messages are not sent. After typing the message and pressing send button, nothing happens, that message doesn't appear in the conversation at all... Someone please help me..

Model : Microsoft Lumia 640 XL
 WhatsApp version : 2.12.276

Comment: How long has it been out? This is likely to be a server error if the problem didn't occur after any app or software update.

Comment: What is your version of WhatsApp? Current version for windows phone is v2.16.14.0. After a update comes, if you do not update it for days you will face this kind of problem. Try updating Whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

An update to [WhatsApp](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/whatsapp/9wzdncrdfwbs)   (Ver. 2.16.2) available, update your WhatsApp. Your problem will be solved.