# Not able to send and receive messages on whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I am not able to send and receive messages on whatsapp. I have reinstalled whatsapp twice but the problem still exists. I can type the message and when i press the push button, that appears on the chat window but it is not sent to the user and it comes up with the waiting clock on chat window. it took my all day to solve the issue. i am using window 8.1.

Comment: Is your internet working well?

Comment: Yes It is working perfectly!!

Comment: Related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12600/not-able-to-send-receive-messages-in-whatsapp?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried with WiFi connection to isolate the issue?